# How to prove this function is concave?

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-analysis

This is the function:

$\displaystyle f(\vec x) = \log \frac{\exp(x_1)}{\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(x_i)} $

Comment: Please do not cross post between mathoverflow and math.stackexchange.

Comment: Irrelevant parts of the question were removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick arbitrary $x,y$ and $\alpha,\beta \in (0,1),\ \alpha+\beta=1$. You want to prove that $f(\alpha x +\beta y) \geq \alpha f(x)+\beta f(y)$. This is equivalent to

$$ \log \frac{e^{\alpha x_1+\beta y_1}}{\sum e^{\alpha x_i+\beta y_i}} 
 \geq \log \frac{e^{\alpha x_1+ \beta y_1}}{(\sum e^{x_i})^\alpha (\sum e^{y_i})^\beta} $$

and equivalently

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n e^{\alpha x_i+\beta y_i}\leq (\sum_{i=1}^n e^{x_i})^\alpha (\sum_{i=1}^n e^{y_i})^\beta $$

which is exactly [Holder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) in the discrete case (note that $\alpha +\beta=1$.

Comment: I don't think this solution works for $g$. Maybe if you come up with some relations between $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s then you may apply something similar.